Windows Server 2022, DC Promo - Server manager closes abruptly
I have Windows Server 2022 virtual machine (Hyper-V Host, same OS) on which I am trying to deploy a second domain controller. I successfully installed the AD Domain Services Role. But when I try to promote the server to DC, it wont let me populate the dsrm password fields. When I click on the fields, server manager (DC Promo Window) just closes abruptly.
I have update the server to the lates cumulative updates.
I have tried rebooting several times
I have tried reinstalling the roles
I have tried promoting it as a new forest, just for testing
I have run SFC/Scannow and DISM repair and ChkDsk
I have tried disabling Windows Security, defender firewall
I have deployed Directory services a thousand times, but never faced something liked this. Why could this happening?
Edit, even DC promo (Install-ADDSDomainController) via powershell, but the process hangs at DNS installation.

Event logs, your friend they are.
